# 'SparseTensor' object is not subscriptable keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Following my Studies in Machine learning I am now in the Neural network, I have an assignment - text Classification - using Neural Network.

In the following, I am showing what I have so far

1. Process Data
2. Counter Vectorizer

Now I'm trying to compile the NN However I am receiving the following
error

> TypeError: 'SparseTensor' object is not subscriptable
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 242, in **call**
> return func(device, token, args)
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 131, in **call**

My data shape is the following

```
X_train.shape = (17621, 8014)

type(X_train) = scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

The model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1015, input_shape=(17621, 8014) , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train,epochs=500,batch_size=125,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

in addition, I have 2 more question

1. What are the differences between input_shape ~ Input_dimmension?
2. when I add the first Layer. How many perceptrons should I set?
3. the most important one what Am I doing wrong?

Please feel free to give more suggestion

Comment: I cannot recreate your error. Which Tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Marcus  I figured out the solution . it seems that tensorflow.keras wasnt working with scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix then I use np.array and works properly

Answer (score 5):

Keras can't work with csr_matrix. Convert to a numpy array.

```
X_train = X_train.toarray()
```